# javascript for click functionality for image whose id is dynamically issued in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-mobile

am having javascript functionality for images whose id is dynamically assigned as like_1,like_2.........., how to make the functionality to made to work for every image these images are in li tag in wow slider.

this is javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#like_0").click(function() {
            $("#tipid").val(1);
            $("#like_0").attr("src","images/ic_like_select.png");
            $("#unlike_0").attr("src","images/ic_unlike_unselect.png");
          });

          $("#unlike_0").click(function() {
            $("#tipid").val(0);
            $("#like_0").attr("src","images/ic_like_unselect.png");
            $("#unlike_0").attr("src","images/ic_unlike_select.png");
          });
          });
    </script>
```

this is the data which is sliding, am getting it from database dynamically

```
<div id="wowslider-container1">
                      <form action="#" method="post">
                            <div class="ws_images">

                            <ul>
                            <?php

                             if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']))) {
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                                    $counter =0;
                                    foreach ($int_arr as $x) {


                                        if ($stmt1->execute(array($x))) {
                                           while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch()) {
                                           // print_r($row);
                                           //echo $row1['title'];

                             ?>

                             <li><img src="engine1/bg.png" alt="" title="" id="wows1"/><div><span style="font-size:12px;text-transform:uppercase;"><b><?php echo $_GET['id'];?></b></span><br><span style="color:#3B8BD7;font-size:22px;"><?php echo $row1['title'];?></span></div><img src="images/list_hr.png" style="background-repeat:repeat-x;width:303px;height:4px;margin-top:-3px;" /><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $row1['body'];?><br><br><br></span><img src="images/list_hr.png" style="background-repeat:repeat-x;width:303px;height:4px;"/><div align="center"><b><p style="color:#3B8BD7;font-size:14px;">Helpline?</p></b><img src="images/ic_like_unselect.png" height="40" width="40" id="like_<?php echo $counter;?>" name="offer" />&nbsp;<img src="images/ic_unlike_unselect.png"  height="40" width="40" id="unlike_<?php echo $counter;?>"  name="offer"/></div>
                             <input type="hidden" name="tipid" id="tipid" value="" />
                             <input type="text" name="tip" id="tip" value="<?php  echo $counter;?>" /><?php $counter++;?></li>
<?php }}}}}  echo $counter;?>
                            </ul></div>
                            <div class="ws_bullets">
                            <div align="center">
                                <?php if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['id']))) {
                                    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                                       foreach ($int_arr as $x) {
                                          if ($stmt1->execute(array($x))) {
                                          while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch()) {
                                          // print_r($row);
                                          //echo $row1['title'];
                                ?>
                                <a href="#" ></a>
                                <?php }}}}}?>           
                            </div></div>

    <div class="ws_shadow">

                    </div>

        </form>
```

as you see in the javascript i gave like_0 and it is working for first slide images, i have to make it work for all the images in other slides also but how to give it is not known can someone help me please thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class, instead of an id. That is what classes are for - remember a class can apply to multiple elements, and an ID only to one.

Example:

```
$(".like").click(function() {
      $(this).closest(".tipid").val(1);
      $(this).attr("src","images/ic_like_select.png");
      $(this).closest('.unlike').attr("src","images/ic_unlike_unselect.png");
});
```

Comment: can you please give an example

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ID's which start with like/unlike, you can use attribute selector instead.

```
$("[id^='like_']" ).click(function() {
     //do something
});    

$("[id^='unlike_']" ).click(function() {
     //do something
});
```